# Retrieving new column to database after doing query

Tags: mysql, sql

**My sql is :**

```
SELECT * FROM stores ORDER BY ST_Distance(location,Point(0,0)) ASC
```

**What it is doing :**

It Retrieves rows in ascending order based on Spatial Point field called location

**What i want to achieve :**

I want to make this sql retrieve distance for each row also

Comment: You want to select the `ST_Distance` and don't know how to put this into your `SELECT` clause?

Comment: i'm newbie sorry :'D

Comment: i want to create field after doing this query for distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not select the value?

```
SELECT s.*, ST_Distance(location,Point(0,0))  as distance
FROM stores s
ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

Comment: thanks i know that's basics but i'm so newbie in this field i start learning from 4 days ago :''D

Comment: @MohamedGaber . . . Hey, that's how you learn.  Cheers.